# How to merge multiple matrices with different columns?

Tags: r, join, matrix, merge, bind

I have a loop in R that always has a matrix as output. Two examples (my data is more complex and has more columns):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 |
| 1 | -1 |

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| -1 | -1 |
| -1 | -1 |

I want to get a combination like this as my output:

| A | B | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -1 | 0 |
| 1 | -1 | 0 |
| -1 | 0 | -1 |
| -1 | 0 | -1 |

So the goal is to bind the rows if the column is already existent (A). If the column is not existent (D), then add a new column for it. And fill the other entries with zeros.

I think a matrix or data frame as the output would be fine. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put them in a `list`, and then after your loop use `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist(fill = TRUE)`. Both will fill with `NA`, not `0`, but you can then covert the `NA`s to `0`s. (And you may need to convert each item to data frame first)

Comment: What will be the results if A was positive in the second dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I propose:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "A", all = TRUE)
```

But have NA instead of zero.

Comment: This relies on all the matrices having an `"A"` column, which isn't clear if it's the case. And I think it will not do what OP wants if two matrices have an `"A"` column that have matching values.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (the matrices need to be converted to data.frame before using `bind_rows`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(.x, 0))) 

#>       A  B  D
#> [1,]  1 -1  0
#> [2,]  1 -1  0
#> [3,] -1  0 -1
#> [4,] -1  0 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use `rbind.fill` from `plyr`:

```r
m1 <- read.table(text="A    B
1   -1
1   -1", header = TRUE)
m2 <- read.table(text = "A  D
-1  -1
-1  -1", header = TRUE)

m3 <- plyr::rbind.fill(m1, m2)
m3
#>    A  B  D
#> 1  1 -1 NA
#> 2  1 -1 NA
#> 3 -1 NA -1
#> 4 -1 NA -1
m3[is.na(m3)] <- 0
m3
#>    A  B  D
#> 1  1 -1  0
#> 2  1 -1  0
#> 3 -1  0 -1
#> 4 -1  0 -1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since `merge` also works with `"data.frame"`s, we may use the usual `Reduce / merge` approach where we put all the matrices into a `list`.  (It might be advantageous if your loop already throws such a list.)

```
Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(m1, m2, m3))
#    D  A  B  F
# 1 -1 -1 NA -1
# 2 -1 -1 NA -1
# 3 -1 -1 NA -1
# 4 -1 -1 NA -1
# 5 NA  1 -1 NA
# 6 NA  1 -1 NA
```

We can refine the result,

```
res <- Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(m1, m2, m3)) |>
  {\(.) subset(., select=order(colnames(.)))}() |>  ## order columns
  {\(.) replace(., is.na(.), 0)}()  ## turn NA to 0
res
#    A  B  D  F
# 1 -1  0 -1 -1
# 2 -1  0 -1 -1
# 3 -1  0 -1 -1
# 4 -1  0 -1 -1
# 5  1 -1  0  0
# 6  1 -1  0  0
```

where:

```
class(res)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

---

*Data:*

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 1L, -1L, -1L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("A", "B")))

m2 <- structure(c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("A", "D")))

m3 <- structure(c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("D", "F")))
```